# Determine which operator has the following form when expressed in matrix spinor notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, spinors

I am new to spinor notation and I came across the following matrix:

What operator has the following form when expressed in matrix spinor notation;

$[[W]]=\frac{\hbar \xi}{2} \begin{pmatrix}\hat L_z & \hat L_x-i\hat L_y\\ \hat L_x +i\hat L_y&-\hat L_z\end{pmatrix}$.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operator is 
$$
\frac{\hbar \xi }{2} \sum_{i=1}^3 \sigma_i \otimes \hat L_i ,
$$
which some write as 
$$
\xi~ {\mathbf S}\cdot {\mathbf L}~.
$$
Is this what you have in mind?